# Restart Cassandra Decommission after it failed

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

I have a Cassandra cluster and am in process of replacing a few nodes. I have added three new nodes to the cluster, and then I started the decommissioning process. The decommission failed after streaming some data, and I see the following errors in logs:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: null
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:211) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:54) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:268) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

and

```
[Stream #24830500-6b64-11eb-947a-59493eec1952] Streaming error occurred
java.lang.AssertionError: Memory was freed
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory.checkBounds(SafeMemory.java:103) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory.getLong(Memory.java:260) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata.getTotalSizeForSections(CompressionMetadata.java:259) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.FileMessageHeader.size(FileMessageHeader.java:133) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.fileSent(StreamSession.java:561) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:49) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.OutgoingFileMessage$1.serialize(OutgoingFileMessage.java:40) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.serialize(StreamMessage.java:48) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.sendMessage(ConnectionHandler.java:370) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$OutgoingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:350) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

The node is now stuck in `UL` state. I found multiple answers on Stackoverflow and Datastax suggesting to use `nodetool removenode` but I want to stream the data from this node to make sure there is no data loss due to inconsistencies in the cluster as the RF is 2. I wasn't able to find a way to restart this process. Is there a way the decommission process can be restarted? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Facing same issue, in my case there is no error. But there are no streams in netstats command since last 2 days.

Comment: I restarted the node and the node moved back to the UN state. I have started the decommission again. I am not sure if this approach would solve your issue.

For your issue, did you check the logs? There was another issue if you run ```nodetool drain``` before starting the decommission. You shouldn't do that. Reference: https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205267926-Node-stuck-in-LEAVING-state-after-being-decommissioned

If you are facing an issue due to socket timeout, you can increase this config ```streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms``` to a high value (like a day).